# Finding all records without associated ones

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have a teams table and a players table and I'm wanting to find all teams that do not have players associated with them. The players table is associated via a `team_id` column. I'm using Ruby on Rails for this so I have a Team and a Player model.

Comment: Which dialect of SQL are you using?

Comment: Ideally this should work with MySQL, Postgres and Sqlite3

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It may perform better doing a left join:

```
SELECT
teams.*
FROM teams
LEFT JOIN players ON (teams.id = players.team_id)
WHERE
players.team_id IS NULL
```

Or using ARel (thanks to JasonKing's comment):

```
Team.includes(:players).where('players.team_id IS NULL')
```

Comment: Perfect, and I'm using Rails too (something I should've mentioned, I guess) so this ties in nicely with the :joins and :conditions syntax.

Comment: No need to use SQL for the join, that's what `includes()` does.  Ie. `Team.includes(:players).where('players.team_id IS NULL')`

Comment: One last finesse: `Team.includes(:players).where( :players => { :team_id => nil } )`

Comment: Hooray modern Ruby: `Team.includes(:players).where( players: { team_id: nil } )`

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
select * from teams
where id not in (select distinct team_id from players)
```

Comment: The downside with this approach: is going to take a while if you have a lot of players records

Answer (score 2):

You'd do that with a `NOT EXISTS` condition like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM teams
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM players WHERE players.team_id = teams.team_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should generally be able to do an outer join from parent to child and check for a null value in a field in the child that is not null-able. This is generally faster than a 'not in' or 'not exists'. This may not work on all databases.