# rails scope filtering

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, set

Hey guys, I have the following scope:

```
scope :expires_within, lambda 
 {|time| where("created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", 30.days.ago, 
                                                      time.from_now - 30.days)}
```

It's not all that important, it works.

This simply gives me all of the objects in my database which were created within a certain time frame. What I want to do is filter this scope such that it removes some of the objects.

The above scope is on a model named **Post**. I have another model named **Lock** which "*belongs to*" a **Post**, and each **Post** "*has many*" **Locks**. So this means that there is a foreign key on each lock with the id of its corresponding Post.

What I want to accomplish is the following: I want to filter out the posts from the above scope which do *not* have any locks. So from an abstract/high-level view: I want to get the posts returned from the above scope and remove any which have any associated locks (even if just one).

Is this possible? Would I have to use some form of compound query, using something like `except`? I'd appreciate any help.

I currently have something that works, but I have a nagging feeling that it isn't very efficient, perhaps it can be done on the database by modifying the above scope and be more efficient:

```
Post.expires_within(1.day) - Lock.all.collect { |lock| lock.post }
```

So this basically gets the collection of posts, then it fetches each of the locks' posts and dumps them all into an array which is then subtracted from the original set of posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone who has already experienced this problem was kind enough to help me out on IRC (Radar), and pointed me to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314408/finding-all-records-without-associated-ones/1314431#1314431). Now my new scope is the following:

```
scope :not_locked, lambda { joins("LEFT JOIN locks on
  (posts.id = locks.post_id)").where("locks.post_id IS NULL") }
scope :expires_within, lambda {|time| where("posts.created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?",
  30.days.ago, time.from_now - 30.days).not_locked }
```

And it works very well. Hope that helps anyone else out there with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

With plain `ActiveRelation`, string-based `LEFT JOIN`s are unavoidable; however, you can greatly simplify the `BETWEEN` calculations using the Ruby `Range` class:

```
scope :expires_within, lambda { |time| 
  where(:created_at => 30.days.ago..(time.from_now - 30.days)) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be do it with a subquery, something like...

```
scope :without_locks, :conditions => "not exists(select * from locks where posts.id = locks.post_id)"
```