# Rails 3: How can I find an object with no children in it

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model, controller

I have a 3 models

```rb
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :clock_ins

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :clock_ins, :allow_destroy => true
end

class ClockIn < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :task, :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :clock_out
end

class ClockOut < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :clock_in, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Currently I can create a `ClockIn` for each `Task`.

When I start a new `ClockIn`, I want to create a `ClockOut` for whichever `Task` is currently open.

How do I search my tasks for one with a `ClockIn` that does not have a `ClockOut`?

---

### Solution

- Combine Models
- Fix destroys
- Iterate all tasks then update `task.clocks.where(:clock_out => nil).first.update_attribute :clock_out, Time.now`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding all records without associated ones](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314408/finding-all-records-without-associated-ones)

Comment: Please check the "Finding all records without associated ones" question.

Comment: It's close, but since I'm digging one layer deeper into the relationships, it's not quite the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have a one-to-one relation between clock_in and clock_out, switching `has_one` and `belongs_to` shouldn't make much difference. What is the data stored in clock_in and clock_out? if is is just a datetime you might want to consider merging the two models and using a single table. If you do not want to change any of the modeling `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is the way to go. So you have three options:

- Merge the models:

  ```
  class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :working_hours

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :working_hours, :allow_destroy => true
  end

  class WorkingHour < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :task

    # has two columns clock_in_time and clock_out_time
  end

  task.working_hours.where(:clock_out_time => nil).first.update_attribute(:clock_out_time => Time.now)
  ```
- Switch has_one and belongs_to

  ```
  class ClockIn < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :task
    belongs_to :clock_out
    # now clock_ins will have column check_out_id
  end

  class ClockOut < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :clock_in
    # doen't have any check_in_id
  end

  task.clock_ins.where(:clock_out_id => nil).first.create_clock_out(:time => Time.now)
  ```
- Go with the outer join

  ```
  class ClockIn < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :task
    has_one :clock_out

    scope :has_no_check_out, {
      :joins => "LEFT OUTER JOIN clock_outs ON clock_ins.id = clock_outs.clock_in_id"
      :conditions => "clock_outs.clock_in_id IS NULL"
    }
  end

  task.clock_ins.has_no_check_out.first.create_clock_out(:time => Time.now)
  ```

Please note that your `:dependent => :destroy` definitions don't look very good. Currently if you destroy a clock_out, corresponding clock_in will be destroyed, resulting in corresponding task being destroyed and leaving other clock_ins related with the task orphaned. Also when the task is destroyed, it will result in user being destroyed. This seems to be very odd chain of events. Destroying a  clock_out, results in destroying a user, Ouch!

You should use `:dependent => :destroy` like following:

```
# user.rb
has_many :tasks, :dependent => :destroy

# task.rb
has_many :clock_ins, :dependent => :destroy

# clock_in.rb
has_one :clock_out, :dependent => :destroy
```

Comment: Fixing the destroys now.  Going to try changing the models, once I get it working I'll mark answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Since the last clock-in could be in another task, it looks like the query might not be quite accurate.

Comment: I ended up using
    task.clocks.where(:clock_out => nil).first.update_attribute :clock_out, Time.now