# How can I filter my query to show instances where current user has no tags?

Tags: sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, tagging, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm trying to show only brand instances which the current user has not tagged, even if other users have tagged the same brand already. Something like:

[image]

**Controller**

This is my controller code and even though it should be working, it currently returns all brand instances.

```
@brand = current_user.brands.includes(:taggings).where( [ "taggings.id IS NULL OR taggings.tagger_id != ?", current_user.id ] ).order("RANDOM()").first
```

Schema (including my join model for good measure)

```
create_table "brand_users", :force => true do |t|
t.integer  "brand_id"
t.integer  "user_id"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "taggings", :force => true do |t|
t.integer  "tag_id"
t.integer  "taggable_id"
t.string   "taggable_type"
t.integer  "tagger_id"
t.string   "tagger_type"
t.string   "context"
t.datetime "created_at"
end

add_index "taggings", ["tag_id"], :name => "index_taggings_on_tag_id"
add_index "taggings", ["taggable_id", "taggable_type", "context"], :name => "index_taggings_on_taggable_id_and_taggable_type_and_context"

create_table "tags", :force => true do |t|
t.string "name"
end

end
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63291/sql-select-columns-with-null-values-only

Comment: Thanks, although I'm reluctant to use pure SQL in the controller.

Comment: As far as I know there is no `SELECT * FROM x WHERE * IS NULL` so a  procedure would probably be the only way. Just create a procedure in your DB and call it from the code, you don't have to put the SQL in the code.

Comment: Care to add it in as an answer?

Comment: Have you seen this answer?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314408/finding-all-records-without-associated-ones

Comment: @Simpleton: And what is the `create_table "taggings", :force => true do |t|` line in your question supposed to mean?

Comment: ypercube sorry meant don't have taggings model, not table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you're using the acts-as-taggable-on gem and have the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_tagger
  has_many :brand_users
  has_many :brands, :through => :brand_users
end
```

So you also have the tables in your schema like:

```
create_table "users", :force => true  do |t|
  t.string "name"
end

create_table "brands", :force => true  do |t|
  t.string "name"
end
```

Then the following SQL query should hopefully do what you want (?):

```
SELECT brands.*
FROM brands
WHERE brands.id NOT IN (
    SELECT brands.id
    FROM brands
    INNER JOIN brand_users ON brand_users.brand_id = brands.id
    INNER JOIN taggings ON (taggings.tagger_id = brand_users.user_id AND taggings.tagger_type = 'User')
    WHERE brand_users.user_id = 1 AND taggings.taggable_id = brand_users.brand_id
)
```

To translate this into Rails ORM, I can't get any closer without hard coding the whole sub-select SQL string, something like:

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :brand_users
  has_many :users, :through => :brand_users

  scope :has_not_been_tagged_by_user, lambda {|user| where("brands.id NOT IN (SELECT brands.id
    FROM brands
    INNER JOIN brand_users ON brand_users.brand_id = brands.id
    INNER JOIN taggings ON (taggings.tagger_id = brand_users.user_id AND taggings.tagger_type = 'User')
    WHERE brand_users.user_id = ? AND taggings.taggable_id = brand_users.brand_id)", user.id) }

end
```

(I know you could do this and then use ruby's [.map(&:id).join(',')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307411/not-in-rails) but if this is a large app I think you loose a lot of performance by taking this out of the database, converting it into a string of integers and feeding it back in (as I understand it).)

Then in your controller **I think** you'd do something like:

`@brand = current_user.brands.has_not_been_tagged_by_user(current_user)`

As an aside, I think this would actually then execute an SQL like below (is that right?):

```
SELECT brands.*
FROM users
INNER JOIN brand_users ON brand_users.user_id = users.id
INNER JOIN brands ON brands.id = brand_users.brand_id 
WHERE brands.id NOT IN (
    SELECT brands.id
    FROM brands
    INNER JOIN brand_users ON brand_users.brand_id = brands.id
    INNER JOIN taggings ON (taggings.tagger_id = brand_users.user_id AND taggings.tagger_type = 'User')
    WHERE brand_users.user_id = 1 AND taggings.taggable_id = brand_users.brand_id
) AND users.id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no `SELECT * FROM x WHERE * IS NULL` so a procedure would probably be the only way. Just create a procedure in your DB and call it from the code, you don't have to put the SQL in the code.

You can see an example of such a procedure [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63291/sql-select-columns-with-null-values-only).