# Rails 3. How to get the difference between two arrays?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

Let’s say I have this array with shipments ids.

```
s = Shipment.find(:all, :select => "id")

[#<Shipment id: 1>, #<Shipment id: 2>, #<Shipment id: 3>, #<Shipment id: 4>, #<Shipment id: 5>]
```

Array of invoices with shipment id's

```
i = Invoice.find(:all, :select => "id, shipment_id")

[#<Invoice id: 98, shipment_id: 2>, #<Invoice id: 99, shipment_id: 3>]
```

- Invoices belongs to Shipment.
- Shipment has one Invoice.
- So the invoices table has a column of `shipment_id`.

To create an invoice, I click on New Invoice, then there is a select menu with Shipments, so I can choose "which shipment am i creating the invoice for". So I only want to display a list of shipments that an invoice hasn't been created for.

So I need an array of Shipments that don't have an Invoice yet. In the example above, the answer would be 1, 4, 5.

Comment: 1, 4, 5 is not a list of ids of invoices with no_shipment_id.

Comment: Sorry, corrected question. Thanks for considering it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding all records without associated ones](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314408/finding-all-records-without-associated-ones)

Comment: As of Ruby 2.6 you can use `difference`. [More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639857/rails-3-how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays/53342467#answer-53342467).

Comment: @SRack is the link you provided correct?

Comment: @user5783745 - it was to an answer, which I deleted as it was getting unexplained downvotes. I've undeleted for you, so the link in the comment above should work again. Feel free to give it a thumb if you find it useful :)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

First you would get a list of shipping_id's that appear in invoices:

```
ids = i.map{|x| x.shipment_id}
```

Then 'reject' them from your original array:

```
s.reject{|x| ids.include? x.id}
```

**Note:** remember that reject returns a new array, use reject! if you want to change the original array

Comment: If you are using Rails 3.2.1+ and ActiveRecord you should use pluck: `ids = i.pluck(:id)`

Comment: This is exponentially slower than just doing `x-i`. The larger the arrays the slower it gets. Here's a benchmark I wrote comparing the two methods http://runnable.com/U5Y8g_nsUQokbzNl/benchmark-ruby-array-diff-methods

Comment: @Ryan - yes, but that's not the same thing.

Answer (score 177):

```
a = [2, 4, 6, 8]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4]

a - b | b - a # => [6, 8, 1, 3]
```

Comment: This is the most elegant answer. `a - b` returns any elements in a that are not in b. `b - a` returns any elements in b that are not in a and the | returns the unique set of elements from those 2 results.

Comment: Love this :) Such a nice way to compare array differences

Comment: Great approach, nonetheless, this wont work for duplicate values. For example, if a included to two 4's the second 4 would not show up

Comment: Perfect solution...!

Answer (score 27):

Use substitute sign

```
irb(main):001:0> [1, 2, 3, 2, 6, 7] - [2, 1]
=> [3, 6, 7]
```

Comment: This : `[2, 1] - [1, 2, 3, 2, 6, 7]` returns `[]`. So it makes me curious how you could get the difference from two dynamic arrays regardless of their order.

Comment: @Trip to answer your question, you could do something like this... `(a-b) + (b-a)` where you get the unique values in both arrays, then combine those values together into a single array.

Comment: @Ryan Thank you for shedding some sanity on this comment thread.

Answer (score 16):

Ruby 2.6 is introducing `Array.difference`:

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5 ].difference([1, 2, 4]) #=> [ 3, 3, 5 ]
```

So in the case given here:

```
Shipment.pluck(:id).difference(Invoice.pluck(:shipment_id))
```

Seems a nice elegant solution to the problem. I've been a keen follower of `a - b | b - a`, though it can be tricky to recall at times.

This certainly takes care of that.

Comment: I don't get the expected result. It works the same as `a - b` for me.

Comment: This works great. Except, it's important to note that the order of the Arrays (i.e. which one you call `.difference` on) plays a big role in the result.

Comment: Difference only compares the receiver, it wont return values that are in the 2nd array but not in the first
`[1,2,3].difference([4,5,6]) #=> [1,2,3]` it's equivalent to `a-b`

Answer (score 13):

Pure ruby solution is

`(a + b) - (a & b)`

```
([1,2,3,4] + [1,3]) - ([1,2,3,4] & [1,3])
=> [2,4]
```

Where `a + b` will produce a union between two arrays 
And `a & b` return intersection 
And `union - intersection` will return difference

Answer (score 5):

The previous answer here from pgquardiario only included a one directional difference.  If you want the difference from both arrays (as in they both have a unique item) then try something like the following.

```
def diff(x,y)
  o = x
  x = x.reject{|a| if y.include?(a); a end }
  y = y.reject{|a| if o.include?(a); a end }
  x | y
end
```

Answer (score 5):

This should do it in one ActiveRecord query

```
Shipment.where(["id NOT IN (?)", Invoice.select(:shipment_id)]).select(:id)
```

And it outputs the SQL

```
SELECT "shipments"."id" FROM "shipments"  WHERE (id NOT IN (SELECT "invoices"."shipment_id" FROM "invoices"))
```

---

In **Rails 4+** you can do the following

```
Shipment.where.not(id: Invoice.select(:shipment_id).distinct).select(:id)
```

And it outputs the SQL

```
SELECT "shipments"."id" FROM "shipments"  WHERE ("shipments"."id" NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT "invoices"."shipment_id" FROM "invoices"))
```

And instead of `select(:id)` I recommend the `ids` method.

```
Shipment.where.not(id: Invoice.select(:shipment_id).distinct).ids
```

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with arrays of Strings, it can be useful to keep the differences grouped together.

In which case, we can use Array#zip to group the elements together and then use a block to decide what to do with the grouped elements (Array).

```rb
a = ["One", "Two",     "Three", "Four"]
b = ["One", "Not Two", "Three", "For" ]

mismatches = []
a.zip(b) do |array| 
  mismatches << array if array.first != array.last
end

mismatches
# => [
#   ["Two", "Not Two"], 
#   ["Four", "For"]
# ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s.select{|x| !ids.include? x.id}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22313950)

Comment: It's the select version of the accepted answer. The opposite of using reject. I just don't have enough stack overflow rep to comment on the answer itself

Comment: I imagine this has been downvoted / flagged as it doesn't offer any context (e.g. what are `ids` here?), explanation and is not much different to an existing answer. There's a guide to putting together a solid answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) if it's useful @FezAbbas :)